# my code can run in IDLE but can Not run in sublime text 3 (IndentationError)

Tags: python-3.x

the code can run in idle, but in sublime text3 there are many IndentationErrors

I have checked that there are no mistakes about 'tab' and 'space'(no space between tab)
and I also change the settings in sublime text3 ("draw_white_space" : "all")

still not works

```
def check():
    symbols = r'''`!@#$%^&*()_+-=/*{}[]\|'";:/?,.<>'''
    chars = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'
    nums = '0123456789'
    password = input('please enter the password\n')
    pass_len = len(password)

    while password.isspace() or pass_len == 0:
        password = input('your password is null or include space, please try again\n')

    if pass_len >= 16:
        len_flag = 3
    elif pass_len > 8:
        len_flag = 2
    else:
        len_flag = 1

    str_flag = 0
    for each in password:
        if each in symbols:
            str_flag += 1
            break

    for each in password:
        if each in chars:
            str_flag += 1
            break   

    for each in password:
        if each in nums:
            str_flag += 1
            break

    if len_flag == 1 or str_flag == 1:
        print('low')
    elif len_flag == 2 or str_flag == 2:
        print('medium')
    else:
        print('high')
```

can anybody tell me what happened and how to avoid in next time. thanks a lot

Comment: Try to create another file and see what happens when you run that. If it fails too, there is probably something wrong with your Sublime Text configuration.
If the other file works ok then try rewriting the code manually as there may be some invisible character messing things up.

Comment: your code runs for me in SublimeText3, but instead of using tabs with python, I've found it is more reliable to use consistent spaces, I've set `"translate_tabs_to_spaces": true,` in SublimeText3 settings, and have had no indentation problems, works with your code as well.